# python linux selenium: chrome not reachable

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to run selenium on Ubuntu 16.10 Server, but I'm getting WebDriverException : Message : chrome not reachable (Driver info: chromedriver 2.9.248304, platform=Linux 4.8.0-22-generic x86_64)

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Chrome('usr/bin/chromedriver')
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print(browser.title)
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

Chrome is installed:

```
google-chrome --version
```

Google Chrome 57.0.2987.110

Comment: Shouldn't you write `/usr/bin/chromedriver` (with a leading `/`)?

Comment: I just solved this problem with updating my crome, even though the version I was using was supported by the driver I was using.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding some chrome options helped!

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: The path is different here. I think it is not the options that did the trick, but the path might be incorrect earlier . Check the path you gave in the comment under my answer. It is different.

Comment: I've tried both paths, and only adding those options did the trick

Answer (score 10):

If you're using docker and getting this error I have the solution!

The cause of the problem is chrome running out of memory as documented [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=519952).

You have to add the flag "--shm-size=2g" to the docker run command.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to install chrome. You should have chrome web driver installed.
You can refer this link for details on installation of chromedriver

[How install chrome webdriver](https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/)

Comment: I've installed it, and put it usr/bin/chromedriver

Answer (score 0):

Try down grade chrome version. Download google-chrome old versions here:
https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php

I've verified the following working combination:
google-chrome linux-v52
chromedriver 2.20.353124

jm