# Selenium raise "webDriverException: chrome not reachable" when using driver.get()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was working trying to use the driver.get() from selenium. My first time trying it, it works just fine. But in my subsequent use, it keeps throwing the 'chrome not reachable' error. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

I read several post regarding this problem before but none of the solution works for me.
Here is the error that i got:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-16f6caae91e8> in <module>
----> 1 driver.get('https://google.com/')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334
    335     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)
```

Comment: Can you check your browser and webdriver version?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008622/python-linux-selenium-chrome-not-reachable) solution. Although it for java you can easily implement that in python as well. Try and see if it resolves your issue.